# Как сохранить данные в excel файл?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
from csv import writer
from lxml import html

headers = {
    'accept': 'image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/94.0.0.0 (Edition Yx 02)'

}


#url = 'https://www.divan.ru/category/krovati-i-matrasy'  # делаем запрос на страницу
url = 'https://www.divan.ru/category/krovati'
response = requests.get(url)  # обработка запроса методом get
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')  # создаем суп
item = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'LlPhw'})
nami = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'ImmXq dpmhZ b8BqN ProductName'})


for index, i in enumerate(item, start=1):
    nami = i.find('a', {'class': 'ImmXq dpmhZ b8BqN ProductName'}).text.strip()
    print(f'{index}. {nami}')

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('m.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    content = ["N", "Наименование"]


    worksheet.write_row(0, 1, content)

    for index, i in enumerate(item, start=1):
        nami = i.find('a', {'class': 'ImmXq dpmhZ b8BqN ProductName'}).text.strip()
        writer.write_row([index])
    writer.save()
```

Не записывает данные парсинга. Выдает следующую ошибку:

```py
    writer.write_row([index])
    
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'write_row'
```

Comment: Вот у вас есть код, отвечающий на ваш же вопрос. Что вы от нас хотите - непонятно. В вопросе должно быть пояснено, чем вас ваш код не устраивает.

Comment: @CrazyElf, он не работает. выдает ошибку.

Comment: Какую именно ошибку? По правилам вы должны в вопросе описать желаемое поведение вашего кода, имеющееся поведение кода, прямо в вопросе поместить полный стек-трейс ошибки, если код выдаёт ошибку. Без этой информации нам сложно гадать что не так с вашим кодом.

Comment: @CrazyElf, а куда пояснение писать ? Окно только для кода.

Comment: обычно тут не знаю, как правильно код оформить, а ты почему-то не знаешь, как написать обычный текст. Где написано, что окно только для кода?

Comment: так в чем вопрос-то? Помочь перевести текст ошибки?

Comment: @Эникейщик, нет. Для exel он не понимает writer.write_row([index]) метод write_row в данном случае. Тогда что мне написать, чтобы данные полученные с сайта записались в файл ? write_colums, write_string тоже...Одним словом, что мне написать, чтобы он записал в файл ?

Comment: нет, не "_Для exel он не понимает writer.write_row([index]) метод write_row в данном случае_". Тут пишут, что у ``writer`` нет ``write_row``. С экселем это никак не связано.

Answer (score 2):

Вы вызываете в своем коде write_row() для объекта записи, который является встроенной функцией Python, а не экземпляром модуля xlsxwriter

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
from csv import writer
from lxml import html

headers = {
    'accept': 'image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/94.0.0.0 (Edition Yx 02)'
}

url = 'https://www.divan.ru/category/krovati'
response = requests.get(url)  
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')  
item = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'LlPhw'})

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('m.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    content = ["N", "Наименование"]
    worksheet.write_row(0, 0, content)

    for index, i in enumerate(item, start=1):
        nami = i.find('a', {'class': 'ImmXq dpmhZ b8BqN ProductName'}).text.strip()
        row = [index, nami]
        worksheet.write_row(index, 0, row)
```

Comment: спасибо. Помогло